# Storing compile-time values of arbitrary type in a generic lambda

Tags: c++, templates, lambda

The following C++-20 code allows the abuse of lambdas for the storage of compile-time values:

```cpp
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

consteval auto addItem(auto origin, auto key, auto value) 
    requires (std::is_same_v<void, decltype(origin(key))>) {
    
    auto result = [=](auto arg) constexpr
    {
        if constexpr(std::is_same_v<decltype(arg), decltype(key)>) {
            return value;
        } 
        else if constexpr(!std::is_same_v<void, decltype(origin(arg))>)
        {
            return origin(arg);    
        }
    };

    return result;
}

template<int I> struct index {};

int main()
{
    constexpr auto c = [](auto) {};
    constexpr auto c_ = addItem(c, index<1>{}, "Hello");
    constexpr auto c__ = addItem(c_, index<2>{}, 42);  
    
    // Will fail to compile as expected, since requires clause above kicks in
    // constexpr auto c___ = addItem(c__, index<2>{}, "WAT");  

    std::cout << c__(index<1>{}) << " ";
    std::cout << c__(index<2>{}) << "\n";   
    
    // Will fail to compile as expected, since return type is void 
    // This is the point where I wish I had a more expressive error message
    // std::cout << c__(index<3>{}) << "\n";   
}
```

This is fine, but the public interface is a little bit clumsy, so I want to fix this using the index values directly:

```cpp
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

template<int I>
consteval auto addItem(auto origin, auto value) 
    requires (std::is_same_v<void, decltype(origin(I))>) {
    
    auto result = [=]<int J>() constexpr
    {
        if constexpr(I == J) {
            return value;
        } 
        else 
        {
            // Fails to compile  
            return origin<J>();    
        }
    };

    return result;
}

int main()
{
    constexpr auto c = []<int I>() {};

    constexpr auto c_ = addItem<1>(c, "Hello");
    constexpr auto c__ = addItem<2>(c_, 42);  
    
    std::cout << c__<1>() << " ";
    std::cout << c__<2>() << "\n";   
}
```

This attempt fails with the error message

```
Output of x86-64 clang (trunk) (Compiler #1)
<source>:15:20: error: 'origin' does not name a template but is followed by template arguments
            return origin<J>();    
                   ^     ~~~
```

It looks like auto is not as auto as I had hoped for. Without changing the public interface do you have any idea how to achieve my goal?

Comment: It's not possible, because when you write `constexpr auto c = ...` then you never get an entity that you can directly supply template arguments to, as in `c<I>`. You always get a concrete object (which, of course, may have templated members).

Comment: Since `c.template operator()<2>();` is valid code I tend to diagree ..

Answer (score 2):

As Brian pointed out the direct call `c<1>()`is not possible, but with  extra syntactic code the compiler finally can deduce it:

```cpp
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

template<int I>
consteval auto addItem(auto origin, auto value) 
    requires (std::is_same_v<void, decltype(origin.template operator()<I>())>) {
    
    auto result = [=]<int J>() constexpr
    {
        if constexpr(I == J) {
            return value;
        } 
        else 
        {
            return origin.template operator()<J>();    
        }
    };

    return result;
}

template<int I>
consteval auto get(auto c) {
    return c.template operator()<I>();
}


int main()
{
    constexpr auto c = []<int I>() {};
    c.template operator()<2>();

    constexpr auto c_ = addItem<1>(c, "Hello");
    constexpr auto c__ = addItem<2>(c_, 42);  
    
    std::cout << get<1>(c__) << " ";
    std::cout << get<2>(c__) << "\n";   
}
```

Not exactly the solution requested, but the extra level of indirection hides the syntactic ugliness.